# Why rxjs print data one single character every time?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

This is my code in RxJs6:

```
const observable$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      take(2),
      map(x => interval(1500).pipe(
        map(y => x+':'+y),
        take(2),
        concatAll()
      )),
    );
observable$.subscribe(obs => {
     obs.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
});
```

I expect my code show the result like this:

```
0:0 
1:0 
0:1 
1:1
```

But it actually shows:

[image]

why my code print data only one character every time ? And I think it should work like what i expected above not the actual result. anything wrong i understand about rxjs ?

Comment: Use `concat` instead of `concatAll`

Comment: my code refer higher order observable, i want to print first observable until it reach complete status. and then print second observable data, that's why i use concatAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `concatAll()`. It's typically used to flatten nested Observables but it can work with Promises and arrays (array-like objects) as well. Ant this is exactly what you're seeing here.

It thinks you want to flatten an array even when you have a string so it takes each item in the array (character in your case) and reemits it separately.

However, another question is what you wanted to achieve with `concatAll`.

Comment: because my code refer higher order observable, i want to print first observable until it reach complete status. and then print second observable data, that's why i use concatAll

Comment: But you definitely don't need to be using `concatAll()` where it is now. It looks like using `mergeMap` instead of `map` could do what you want.

Comment: If you could explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve we might be able to come up with a solution. cuz `ob.subscribe(obs => obs.subscribe())` is just a strange way to do things.

Comment: it seems i misunderstand the usage of concatAll, thanks for your help.